# How to redirect a domain to a specific IP and port using nginx?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, mapping

I have read several similar questions to this one in this forum, but not exactly the same, I tried every solution in very different ways but I am not able to manage this.

I was given some data about a server. In this server, I have to install an application which is going to run in `https://localhost:31070/?a=bbb`. I did that, and now, I can access from any computer to the application writing `https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:31070/?a=bbb`. I installed **nginx** on that server as the HTTP server, to make this work.

Now, I was given a domain *my.domain.com*. They want to type *my.domain.com* on the URL and go directly to the application (go to `https://localhost:31070/?a=bbb`). I was working with virtualhosts in **nginx**, but I do not know if this is the right way to manage that.

Anyone can help me? This is my virtualhost:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  my.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:31070/;
    }
}
```

This is stored in a file called **domain** in **/etc/nginx/sites-available/** which is enabled, by the way. I also edited the file **/etc/hosts**, adding the line `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx my.domain.com`. My problem is: if I type *my.domain.com* on the URL, I see nothing.

**EDIT**
I think the virtualhost is OK, but the problem could be that *my.domain.com* is not being recognised by remote hosts.

Comment: This is the third time you've asked a very similar question about this broken application. The solution is to fix the application.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the application is not broken. I managed to do what I want with Apache2 in localhost. But now, I was told to do it with nginx. I tried to follow the same steps as I did in Apache2, but is not the same as I am checking.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Did you take a look at the `proxy_pass` directive in nginx?

Comment: @etagenklo Yes, I am using it. I am going to paste my virtualhost to let you see what I did.

Comment: Is the port 30070 or 31070?

Comment: @etagenklo Sorry I pasted the old code, but in fact, for the moment I do not mind  if it redirects me to 30070 with http or 31070 with https. Because the app is running on both ports with different secure protocols.

Comment: Anything in your nginx log?

Comment: @etagenklo nothing, everything is fine.